# SQLite - Negative value by substracting months of different years

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I am trying to retrieve the month value of a calculation :

```
SELECT strftime('%m', 'now') - strftime('%m', e.date) AS something FROM ...
```

But here are the results I get and what I really want :

```
NOW - 2012-02-03 = 0 // want 11
NOW - 2012-11-02 = -9 // want 3
NOW - 2012-02-02 = 0 // want 12
NOW - 2012-01-02 = 1 // want 13
```

As I can see I can almost get the right values by doing `sqlResult + 12` (except for first example) but is there a way to achieve this directly in the SQL statement and to get exact values in every case ?

**EDIT :** Finally here is the solution

```
SELECT CAST ((julianday('now') - julianday(e.date_retour)) / 30 AS integer) AS something
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really looking at difference between two months but, considering their years as well.

So you need to do like this:

[SQLite (SQL.js) Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/11090/20)

```
SELECT round((julianday(Date('now')) - 
        julianday(Dates))/30) as MonthsDiff
from demo;


| MonthsDiff |
--------------
|       11.0 |
|        2.0 |
```

Comment: Almost perfect except it didn't work for the 3rd example... I don't understand as it is the simplest !?

Comment: Let me give it a try with all your sample data :)

Comment: Still not perfect as it gives me 11 instead of 12 for the 3rd case :/ Probably because you / by 30 but 30 is not the perfect average of number of days in a month.

Comment: I doubt that's the case.. here seems like a bug: closely notice in date 2012-01-08 and 2012-01-02... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2c825/1

Comment: So whithout `round()` I got the right values but I don't care about the **,...** so do you know how to truncate it ?

Comment: Sure let me update you with it. Can you share how you got it working `:D` ?

Comment: To remove the decimal zeros.. u can use : `Cast(x as int)` : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4a9ff/20

Comment: Yeah I found it thanks :) will update my post with the solution. Thx for your help !

Answer (score 3):

You need to take the year into account.  You can do this as:

```
select strftime('%Y', 'now')*12+strftime('%m', 'now') -
       (strftime('%Y', e.date)*12+strftime('%m', e.date))
```

The month returns the month of the year.  So, it is no surprise that something like 2 (February) - 9 (September) produces a negative number.

To handle day of month, I think you have to handle the date arithmetic yourself:

```
select (strftime('%Y', 'now')*12+strftime('%m', 'now') -
        (strftime('%Y', e.date)*12+strftime('%m', e.date))
       ) -
       (case when strftime('%d', 'now') < strftime('%d', e.date) then 0 else 1 end)
```

SQLite has the ability to add months to a date.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have the ability to take the difference in months between dates.

Comment: It works except for the first example :) it gives me 12 instead of 11.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the weird numbers because you are asking the strftime function to return only the month and then you are subtracting only the months...

How about you do this?

```
SELECT strftime('%s', date()) - strftime('%s', '2012-03-03') as blah
```

this will subtract the unix timestamps and then you can convert it back to readable months or whatever...

or this could give you number of days...

```
SELECT julianday(date()) - julianday('2012-03-03') as blah
```